# How to solve "error while loading shared libraries: opencv_world300.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s image_file_name\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR = 1 forces the resultant IplImage to be colour.
    //CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE = 0 forces a greyscale IplImage.
    //CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED = -1
    IplImage* Img1 = cvLoadImage(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    
    // Always check if the program can find a file
    if (!Img1) {
        printf("Error: fichero %s no leido\n", argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // a visualization window is created with title 'image'
    cvNamedWindow(argv[1], CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    // img is shown in 'image' window
    cvShowImage(argv[1], Img1);
    cvWaitKey(0);


    // memory release for img before exiting the application
    cvReleaseImage(&Img1);

    // Self-explanatory
    cvDestroyWindow(argv[1]);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

I have this code written to show a picture of some fruits but I get this error. I'm pretty sure that I have teh correct libraries, what's the point?

I have tried everything, I changed the path of system enviroment and the relative paths.

Comment: Ensure "opencv_world300.dll" in in a folder listed in the PATH variable and its name matches exactly

Comment: This file is in a folder in my desktop. I have listed that exactly folder in the PATH variable by copying the direction, so the names matches as well.

Comment: Are you running your program from the console/prompt?
What do you get if you run `dir %PATH% | findstr "\<opencv_world300.dll\>"` right before trying to execute the program?

Comment: I'm running it from NetBeans 8.2 , which is the version that we should use in that subject